# How to print SQL query result without unwanted characters in python?

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
engine = create_engine('database info',convert_unicode=True) 

result = engine.execute(" select title from table")

line=(result.fetchall())

print(line)
```

Some of the results have "\xa0" inserted in them

Is there a way to return my query so that I don't have to try to fix it after the fact?

Comment: do you get the same results with `convert_unicode=False`

Comment: @JacobIRR yes I get the same result